# Is there a file size limit for which Azure Blob Storage calculates and sets an MD5?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, md5, azure-sdk

I have been working with file uploading using Azure Blob Storage for a while now. However, I have observed that for some of the blobs, the MD5 is an empty string. I can observe this both when retrieving the metadata programmatically (using javascript SDK and the *blob.getProperties()* method and also directly on the Azure Portal when navigating through my storage account.

I have also observed that this seems to happen for large files only (> 1GB). I don't recall seeing one "small" file with this problem. Is there any known file size restriction that would prevent the MD5 from being generated?

And also, does this apply equally when uploading a BlockBlob in chunks (via the SDK methods: i.e. *blockBlobClient.uploadData()*) as when directly using the Blob Storage API ? (via the PUT operation)

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is only calculated by the Storage service for blobs that were uploaded with [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=azure-ad).  This behavior is by design.

Refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties?tabs=azure-ad#response-headers

Content-MD5 If the Content-MD5 header has been set for the blob, this response header is returned so that the client can check for message content integrity.

In version 2012-02-12 and later, Put Blob sets a block blob’s MD5 value even when the Put Blob request doesn’t include an MD5 header.

Comment: so it is independent of the file size? it's just a matter of being using PutBlob? I'm assuming that's what's being used with the uploadData function (for Javascript SDK). I've also done some tests from Postman calling the blob storage API directly (PUT endpoint) and setting the x-ms-blob-type header to BlockBlob. Is that also using the Put Blob behavior?

Comment: Can you share the Postman output?

Comment: The response is an empty body with the 201 status, on the response headers I can observe "Content-MD5" and its value. This seems to be valid for any file as long as they do not exceed the ~5GB size, for those I get a 413 Status.

Comment: When using the SDK, is there a file size threshold for which Azure blob storage won't automatically calculate and store its MD5 hash? I've observed it doesn't for files of 1GB, for example. 
Thank you!

Comment: Hey any chance I could get a reply here? Thank you